# Java - Thymeleaf - HTML: Color letters using switch case: Unwanted paragraph/newline

Tags: java, html, colors, switch-statement, thymeleaf

I am working on a biological database composed of genes, proteins and assays. Using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, I want to establish a web visualisation. Each gene is shown on a page with name, description and sequence. The sequence is composed of the letters A,T,G and C. I want to color those letters (works). But, each letter is written in a new line, instead of the text being written until the line is full (and then to the next line etc). In gene.html, I used the small-tag when defining the colors (tried p before and though of this being the reason for my problem), but using small did not help.

I hope, the code snippets I provide are enough (if not, tell me what you need)

gene.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Gene</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="content/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<!--import header-->
<header th:include="header"></header>

    <div id="main">
        <!--GeneID as page heading -->
        <h2 th:text="'Gene: '+${identifier}"></h2>
        <!--Gene description -->
        <p th:text="${description}"></p>
        <br/>
        <!-- Sequence -->
        <h3 th:text="'Sequence:'"></h3>
        <!-- For each char in sequence-->
        <th:block th:each="char:${sequence}">
            <!--Print the char. Possibility to color encode the bases utilizing switch/case
            <small th:text="${char}"></small> -->
            <div th:switch="${char}">
                <div th:case="'A'">
                    <small  style="color: blue" th:text="${char}"></small>
                </div>
                <div th:case="'T'">
                    <small  style="color: yellow" th:text="${char}"></small>
                </div>
                <div th:case="'C'">
                    <small  style="color: forestgreen" th:text="${char}"></small>
                </div>
                <div th:case="'G'">
                    <small  style="color: red" th:text="${char}"></small>
                </div>
            </div>

        </th:block>

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <!--Protein encoded by gene -->
        <h3>Protein:</h3>
        <a th:href="${'protein?id='+protein}" th:text="${protein}"></a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

GeneController.java

```
package gui.spring.controller;

import db.sample.Gene;
import db.sample.Protein;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Optional;
import static main.Main.query;

/**
 * @author Miriam Mueller
 * @since 05-12-2018
 * @version 1.0
 * Class to handle view of one Gene. Gene name, description and sequence are shown. The encoded protein is linked.
 */
@Controller
public class GeneController {
    //All calls of localhost:8080/gene get to this controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/gene", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String einGenAnzeigen(Model model, @RequestParam(value="id") String id) {

        model.addAttribute("geneSize",query.getGenes().size());
        model.addAttribute("proteinSize",query.getProteins().size());
        model.addAttribute("assaySize",query.getAssays().size());
        Optional<Gene> gene = query.getGeneByName(id);

        if(gene.isPresent()) {
            // if gene exists
            String description = gene.get().getDesc();
            String[] arraySeq = gene.get().getSequence().split("(?!^)");
            Protein protein = query.getGeneByName(id).get().getProtein();
            model.addAttribute("identifier", gene.get().getIdentifier()); //GenID
            model.addAttribute("sequence",arraySeq); //gene sequence
            model.addAttribute("description",description); //description
            model.addAttribute("protein",protein.getIdentifier()); //encoded protein
        }else{
            // error messages, if no gene with called id exists
            model.addAttribute("gene", "There is no Gene with this ID.");
            model.addAttribute("protein","There is no Gene with this ID.Therefore, no reference protein was found.");
            model.addAttribute("sequence","");
            model.addAttribute("description","");
        }

        // name of html-template
        return "gene";
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time and effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the `div` element is a [block](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) element which means that they will stack vertically instead of horizontally. For example as your traverse the sequence:

```
    <th:block th:each="char:${sequence}">
        <!--Print the char. Possibility to color encode the bases utilizing switch/case
        <small th:text="${char}"></small> -->
        <div th:switch="${char}">
            <div th:case="'A'">
                <small  style="color: blue" th:text="${char}"></small>
            </div>
            <div th:case="'T'">
                <small  style="color: yellow" th:text="${char}"></small>
            </div>
            <div th:case="'C'">
                <small  style="color: forestgreen" th:text="${char}"></small>
            </div>
            <div th:case="'G'">
                <small  style="color: red" th:text="${char}"></small>
            </div>
        </div>

    </th:block>
```

every single `div` will be displayed in a new line. You can have them displayed inline by either changing the `display` on those div's to be `inline` or `inline-block`

```
        <div th:case="'A'" style="display:inline-block;">
            <small  style="color: blue" th:text="${char}"></small>
        </div>
        <div th:case="'T'" style="display:inline-block;">
            <small  style="color: yellow" th:text="${char}"></small>
        </div>
        <div th:case="'C'" style="display:inline-block;">
            <small  style="color: forestgreen" th:text="${char}"></small>
        </div>
        <div th:case="'G'" style="display:inline-block;">
            <small  style="color: red" th:text="${char}"></small>
        </div>
```

or using another element whose default display is not `block` e.g. `span`. Removing the `div's` will work as well since `small` is also an inline element.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a style of `float: left` to get your div blocks to line up how you want.

I'd suggest you swap to using an external style sheet to hold your styles. You can then set different classes on your genes and style them that way. It's a lot easier than trying to manage them all in the html. And you could then get rid of that `th:switch` statement.

Create a `main.css` file in `resources/static/css/` with the following content (as an example)

```
div.gene {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    float: left;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
}

div.A {
    color: blue;
}

div.T {
    color: yellow;
}

div.C {
    color: forestgreen;
}

div.G {
    color: red;
}
```

add the following inside the `<head>` tag of your gene html so it can get hold of the css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
```

Change your gene.html to add the classes

replace

```
    <div th:switch="${char}">
        <div th:case="'A'">
            <small  style="color: blue" th:text="${char}"></small>
        </div>
        <div th:case="'T'">
            <small  style="color: yellow" th:text="${char}"></small>
        </div>
        <div th:case="'C'">
            <small  style="color: forestgreen" th:text="${char}"></small>
        </div>
        <div th:case="'G'">
            <small  style="color: red" th:text="${char}"></small>
        </div>
    </div>
```

with

```
    <div th:class="${'gene ' + char}" th:text="${char}"/>
```

This will add a class 'gene' and a class with the char of the gene (e.g. 'A') to the div. The css then has styles for the gene which are common to all, and styles for the char which are specific (i.e. the color)